# What are the domain and name of a function that takes a vector of arbitrary length as argument?

Tags: functions

Is there a name for a function that takes any vector (or list) as argument? And what is its domain?

For example, if $v$ is a vector of arbitrary length, what is the domain of functions such as:

- $f(v) \rightarrow \sum_i v[i]$
- $f(v) \rightarrow dim(v)$

Comment: For $v[i]$ to have a meaning, you need some basis (element of a vector space doesn't have "components" by itself). $\dim$ is a property of a vector space, the same entity $v$ can be found in different vector spaces with different dimensionality.

Comment: Do you speak about mathematical functions or about functions in programming languages (as your words seem to imply: *list*, *v[i]*)?. For mathematical functions there is no need for a dedicated name, e.g. the domain of f may be a Hilbert space like $l^p$

Comment: I'm trying to explain in mathematical terms an algorithm that has been implemented in a programming language, and that involves a function taking a vector of arbitrary length. I was just curious to know if there was such a concept in mathematics.

Comment: You may think about your "vector" $v$ ("list" would be better) of elements from $V$ as $\mathbb{N} \to V^*$, $V^* = V \cup \{\bot_V\}$, that would be your domain. First function then would be $(\mathbb{N} \to V^*) \to V$.

Answer (score 1):

In the first place there is a name for the domain of such a function.

Given a ground set $X$ one can consider words of length $n\geq0$ over the alphabet $X$, which are nothing else but maps $v:\>[n]\to X$, including the empty word $\Lambda$ (or similar letter). The set of all these words when $n$ runs through all the integers $\geq0$ is denoted by $X^*$ (see [Formal Language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_language) in Wikipedia).

This means that the domain  of the functions $f$ you are envisaging is the set
$$X^*=\bigcup_{n=0}^\infty X^n\ .$$